# Generic of T for List<T> items

Tags: c#, generics

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I couldn't find anything similar.

I have an enumerable choice that comes into my class:

```
public enum OrdinalValue
{
   None = 0,
   Qualification = 1,
   Career = 2,
   Faculty = 3
}
```

Based on this enumerable do I have 3 property calls that brings back data from an entity collection for each of these:

```
public List<Qualification> ByQualification { get; set; }
public List<Career> ByCareer { get; set; }
public List<Faculty> ByFaculty { get; set; }
```

I want to create a generic method that returns the correct property, based on the enum passed back from the calling method, something like:

```
public List<T> GetEntities<T>(OrdinalValue ord)
{
    List<T> value = default(List<T>);

    // based on enum, cast the correct List<T> and return value
    // something like:
    if (ord == OrdinalValue.Career)
        return (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(this.ByCareer, typeof(T));

    return value;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The list would already be the passed in type though. `className.GetEntities<Career>(OrdinalValue.Career);` ??

Comment: not really, what if the enum return Faculty? how would i go about changing List<T> based on the enum?

Comment: This isn't useful in general, because somebody who calls it won't know what they have. `OrdinalValue ord = GetOrdinalValue(); var result = GetEntities(ord);` What type is `result`? You don't know at compile time since you don't know what `GetOrdinalValue` is going to return.

Comment: That `enum` is an *enumeration*, not an *enumerable* (nor *enumerator*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
public List<T> GetEntities<T>(OrdinalValue ord)
{
    object ret;

    switch(ord)
    {
        case OrdinalValue.Career:
            ret = ByCareer;
            break;
        case OrdinalValue.Faculty:
            ret = ByFaculty;
            break;
        case OrdinalValue.Qualification:
            ret = ByQualification;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ord");
    }
    return (List<T>) ret;
}
```

However, this doesn't feel like a good design to me. It's hard to suggest anything better without knowing more about the bigger picture, but it doesn't really feel like a truly *generic* method.

Comment: this could work. basically, i have a composite control that will be built, dynamically, based on user input (3 options as specified through the enum). each option so render the control's content differently based on this. so instead of writing a switch with three different method calls, or if...statements, do i want to return the correct entities as List<T> so I can just build the output based on the returning collection. if that makes sense?

Comment: If you have a composite structure then all three classes will implement the same interface.  Have a non generic method that returns a List<thatInterface>.  Use the enum passed in to determine how that list is populated knowing that the caller doesn't care what which concrete type the items in the list are.

Comment: Servy, i use similiar idea but find the object with "if (ord is TheType)" in the method. It's return the complete object if match.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jon is on the right track, there's no point in overcomplicating things here. When maintaining the method gets too complicated you should think about doing it generically all the way.

However, I think his method can be simplified. You don't need to pass the `OrdinalValue` parameter. Instead of checking it, you can check `typeof(T)`. The compiler will need to know T at compile time anyway.